# Is it possible to make an AIR app have a "nag"?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, notifications, flash-builder

Is it possible to make a desktop AIR application that includes the ability to "nag" users every so often to perform an action (similar to Windows status bar notifications or "jumping icons" on the Mac dock)?

Comment: I understand that it could be useful, but at the same time I hope it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bounce() method.  I think this might be what you're looking to try to achieve.

Here's an entire tutorial about doing stuff with the user's dock/system tray on Adobe's DevNet.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/stopwatch_dock_system_tray.html